# Jenkins deploy war file to Tomcat 8 - webpage show error

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, deployment, war-filedeployment

I am trying to deploy `sample.war` file to Tomcat 8 and file deployer successfully. However, when I try to launch http://localhost:8080/sample/ it show me following error on the web page:
[image]

After deployment following is success log:

```
Started by user admin
Building on master in workspace C:\Users\name\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest
[AutomatedDeploymentTest] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson6142418824859478059.bat

C:\Users\name\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest>exit 0 
[AutomatedDeploymentTest] $ sh -xe C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3975448203686724676.sh
+ dir
sample.war
+ date
Tue, Jun 20, 2017  8:45:09 AM
Deploying C:\Users\name\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest\sample.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  Redeploying [C:\Users\name\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest\sample.war]
  Undeploying [C:\Users\name\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest\sample.war]
  Deploying [C:\Users\name\.jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeploymentTest\sample.war]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I am not sure why webpage is not displaying app up and running since war file deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just launch url as `http://localhost:8080/sample.war` insted of  `http://localhost:8080/sample/` and it worked for me. I am not sure why I need to enter sample.war with extension `.war` but it worked finally.